# Using React hooks in dynamically loaded modules for multiple deployments

Tags: reactjs

I have a react project running for client #1.
With the same code, I want to be able to change logic dynamically for client #2 (each one is a different deployment).

I want to add something like this (pseudo code) for client #2:

parent.js:

```
new_filtered = props.menu_data.filter((obj) => obj.id === new_id);
// if hook file exists, it will override the value of post_menu_res 
const post_menu_res = await checkAddon( 'PostMenuSelection',{data:new_filtered},new_filtered);
if (post_menu_res?.abort === true) {
    return;
}
```

AddonController.js:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export const checkAddon = async (addon_name, params,default_res=null) => {
    try {
        const module = await import(`../addons/${addon_name}`);
        const hookValues = {
            useSelector: useSelector,
            useTranslation: useTranslation
        }
        const res = module.default(params, hookValues);
        return res;
    } catch (err) {
        return default_res;
    }
}
```

PostMenuSelection.js:

```
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import {getLoginResults} from "../redux/selectors";

const PostMenuSelection = (data, hooks ) => {

  const {useTranslation, useSelector} = hooks;
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const teststr = t("exam_not_allowed", "Not Allowed"),

  const new_filtered = data.new_filtered;
  const loginResult = useSelector(getLoginResults);

  if (add_data?.exams !== "undefined") {
    const examStatus = add_data.exams.find(
      (item) => parseInt(item.id) === parseInt(new_filtered[0].exam_id)
    );
    if ( ..some condition.. ) {
      Swal.fire({...});
      return {abort:true};
    }
  }
  return {};
};

export default PostMenuSelection;
```

But this code doesn't work since hooks (useTranslation, useSelector) can only be called inside of the body of a function component (and PostMenuSelection isn't).

(`hookValues` inside AddonController was an attempt to bypass this restrication).

I want PostMenuSelection to self contain all the logic it needs.

Anyway to achieve something like this?